# How to synchronize jquery load files with jquery bind events

Tags: javascript, oop, jquery, jquery-load

I need to add to DOM some html´s by jquery, and bind some events the generated elements, but i cant syncronize it, where the addEvents function starts, the DOM elements are not created, so the $(".login-log") element is not on DOM yet.

I found this:

[Javascript Event Synchronization](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1076154/javascript-event-synchronization)

Im working on it but dont works for me, that my code, i dont know if i miss something or what:

```
var Login = function ()
{
var commons = new Commons();

this.init = function()
{
    stepOne(stepTwo);

    commons.init();
}

function stepOne(callback) {
    var AsyncDone = function()
    {
        callback();
    }
    loadFiles(AsyncDone);
}

function loadFiles(callback)
{
    $(".header-container").load("views/header.html");
    $(".content-container").load("views/login.html");
    callback();
}

function stepTwo() {
    addEvents();
}

function addEvents() {
    alert("is here");
    $(".login-log").bind("click", function() { alert("fuck"); });
}
}
```

The syncronizathion makes the alert "is here" to appear before the DOM elements of header and login.html are loaded in DOM.

I know that have to be simple, but i dont find the solution.

Thanks in advice.

Comment: What doesn't work? You need to improve this question to ask a specific question, see the http://stackoverflow.com/faq

Comment: I need to add to DOM some html´s by jquery, and bind some events to that elements i generate, but i cant syncronize it, where the addEvents function starts, the DOM elements are not created, so the $(".login-log") element is not on DOM yet.

Comment: I think is clear here: "The syncronizathion makes the alert "is here" to appear before the DOM elements of header and login.html are loaded in DOM." Dont put a negative vote and try to understand the question before...

Comment: Your `loadFiles` function invokes the callback before the two load has happened. Btw, those stepOne and stepTwo are completely unnecessary, just call `loadFiles(addEvents)`

Answer (score 1):

My final choose:

```
this.init = function()
{
    loadHeader(addHeaderEvents);
    loadTemplate(addTemplateEvents);
    loadFooter(addFooterEvents);

    commons.init();

}

function loadHeader(callback) {
    $(".header-container").load("views/header.html", function() {
        callback();
    });
}
function addHeaderEvents() {

}

function loadTemplate(callback) {
    $(".content-container").load("views/template_login.html", function() {
        callback();
    });
}
function addTemplateEvents() {
    alert("llega");
    $(".login-log").bind("click", function() { alert("done"); });
}

function loadFooter(callback) {
    $(".footer-container").load("views/footer.html", function() {
        callback();
    });
}
function addFooterEvents() {

}
```